# Transposed content issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

trust you're good. I'm working on a project where I sent data from an apk to a google sheet.
The fact is that I sent the whole data to a sheet and I also send a kind of transposed data to other sheets, all with [custom IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69151156/unique-id-predated-by-predefined-text).

Example here:

In Test_Sheet: `ID` `Region` `Place` `Staff` `thing1` `thing2` `thing3` `thing4` `thing5`

In test2 sheet:

`ID` `thing1`

`ID` `thing2`

`ID` `thing3`

`ID` `thing4`

`ID` `thing5`

All works fine but my issue is that when I have fewer items only, the ID will still be in the test2 sheet like all items are present.

`ID` `thing1`

`ID` `thing2`

`ID` `thing3`

`ID`

`ID`

Here is the code:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Test_Sheet');
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('test2')

  //custom ID 
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var counter = scriptProperties.getProperty('counter') || 0;
  var formatDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "ddMMyy");
  var zero = (counter < 10) ? '0' : '';
  var ID = "T" + formatDate + zero + counter++;
    if (counter > 99) counter = 0;
  scriptProperties.setProperty('counter', counter);

  \\send from apk
  var region = e.parameter.region;
  var place = e.parameter.place;
  var staff = e.parameter.staff;
  var thing1= e.parameter.thing1;
  var thing2= e.parameter.thing2;
  var thing3= e.parameter.thing3;
  var thing4= e.parameter.thing4;
  var thing5= e.parameter.thing5;
  
\\Test_Sheet
  sh.appendRow([ID, region, place, staff, thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4, thing4]);

\\test2
  sh2.appendRow([ID, thing1]);
  sh2.appendRow([ID, thing2]);
  sh2.appendRow([ID, thing3]);
  sh2.appendRow([ID, thing4]);
  sh2.appendRow([ID, thing5]);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that the new rows are created even though an ID does not exists for these records, then first make sure that the ID does exist before writing to the sheet. So in your code, you would do:

```js
 if( thing1 ) sh2.appendRow([ID, thing1])
 if( thing2 ) sh2.appendRow([ID, thing2]) 
 // … and so on
```